# What does it mean to "render a view"? What the procedure is this?

Tags: php, zend-framework, rendering

I can't understand what is "rendering a view". I'm reading Zend Framework manual and there are a lot of usage of this term.

Automatically rendering views:

> This helper takes care of injecting the view object into the
>   controller, as well as automatically rendering views.

Disable rendering for a view:

> You can also simply disable rendering for an individual view

`render()` renders a view script.

> render() renders a view script.

Render that template in the subdirectory

> Passing a value for $action will render that template in the
>   /[controller]/ subdirectory.

And so on.

I found the `render()` method. I fact many component classes of `Zend_Controller` have `render()` method. But all of them at long last anyway call only the one from the `Zend_View_Abstract` class. And the only thing I could see in its realization is that it seems it just puts the html-script into the output buffer:

```
public function render($name) {

        // find the script file name using the parent private method
        $this->_file = $this->_script($name);
        unset($name); // remove $name from local scope

        ob_start();
        $this->_run($this->_file);

        return $this->_filter(ob_get_clean()); // filter output
    }
```

Unfortunately there is no realization of the `_run()` method and I don't know what it has to do, how to include script in a scope. Is this what is meant by include - `include_once("/myScritp.php")`?

```
/**
 * Use to include the view script in a scope that only allows public
 * members.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
 abstract protected function _run();
```

So what does it mean to "render a view"? Just to include the script and put it into the output buffer and get it in some variable (`return ob_get_clean()`) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework is based on MVC design pattern which stands for Model View Controller. The View is presentation part including html, javascript, css or any other aesthetics.

**Rendering a view** means showing up a View eg html part to user or browser. Let's say you have a controller for About page of your site, now from your controller you would render the About view which means **show the that page in browser for users to see** otherwise if you don't users will see just blank page :)

Think of it `echo`ing html/css/js to browser.

Comment: I thought about it but to show the page in the browser I have the `Response` class and its method `sendResponse()`. It just exactly sends all the headers and after headers outputs the body. Why then there is also `render()` method for the same task? Thank you

Comment: @Green: Those are used a bit differently in correct context for each. You should see docs or ask a new question about the difference between the two which will get you to better answers there :)

Answer (score 4):

A View is part of an MVC framework, which is what Zend is.  Think of the View as the output to the user.  The Controller handles actions and routing, in a sense, and the model handles mostly database interactions.  The View sets up variables and sends them to the HTML output when the page is rendered.

So by `rendering a view`, the MVC framework has handled the data in the controller and done the backend work in the model, and then sends that data to the View to be output to the user.

Answer (score 0):

`render` just means to emit.  To print.  To echo.  To write to some source (probably stdout).

Comment: I don't think, this definition is correct. IMO renderning is the process of filling a template with living data, replacing placeholders and logic resulting in a valid html file, for example. This does not necessarily mean you echo it right now, it could also just be assigned to a variable for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Say, we are talking about HTML:

Rendering is the process of filling a template with living data from your application, replacing placeholders and simple logic (like if-else statements or loops) resulting in a valid html file.