# What is the difference between "render a view" and send the response using the Response's method "sendResponse()"?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, symfony1, rendering, httpresponse

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233442/what-does-it-mean-to-render-a-view-what-the-procedure-is-this) about what is "rendering a view". Got some answers:

> Rendering a view means showing up a View eg html part to user or
>   browser.

and

> So by rendering a view, the MVC framework has handled the data in the
>   controller and done the backend work in the model, and then sends that
>   data to the View to be output to the user.

and

> render just means to emit. To print. To echo. To write to some source
>   (probably stdout).

but don't understand then the difference between `rendering a view` and using the `Response` class to send the output to the user using its `sendResponse()` method. If `render a view` means to echo the output to the user then why `sendResponse()` exists and vise versa? `sendResponse()` exactly sends headers and after headers outputs the body. They solve the same tasks but differently? What is the difference?

Comment: Are you talking Zend Framework in particular?

Comment: I'm examining Zend Framework to understand what is MVC. So not Zend Framework in particular. Symfony also uses `render a view` term and doesn't have much info about what it is too.

Comment: @Green you will find many if not all mvc frameworks use very similar terminology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ZF, rendering a view doesn't actually output any content.  Instead the rendering process returns the content as a string to the caller.  `Zend_Application` automatically takes care of taking the rendered view and inserting it into your layout (assuming you use layouts) through a placeholder, and putting that data into the `Zend_Controller_Response_Http` object which is ultimately responsible for delivering the content to the user.  The reason for the Response object is so it can encapsulate your HTML output, and also manage any additional HTTP headers or redirects you want to send.

You can also manipulate further the contents of the response in the Response object prior ot sending the data to the client if you wish.

`sendResponse()` takes care of sending any headers (including the HTTP response code), checking for any exceptions that may have occurred (due to not being able to send headers or other reasons) and then sends the HTML which could include your layout and one or more rendered view scripts.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

They are two very different things.

Rendering a view provides another layer in which you can template your data.  This will allow you to easily dynamically populate HTML/templates keeping logic seperate from presentation.

Echoing data directly skips this step, and is usally reserved for reterning json/xml (data) responses to user instead of html response.

You didn't post which framework you are talking about but both should allow you to specify response headers.

Please don't oversimplify.  Every server's purpose is to render resource but that doesn't mean they are all the same.